# bind propertygrid in wpf without refreshing it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Below is the code of binding data into dropdown list of the property grid.

```
[Category(Constants.ColumnScrambler), PropertyOrder(2)]
[DisplayName(Constants.Condition)]
[Description(Constants.Condition)]
[ItemsSource(typeof(CustomColumnConditionProperty))]
public ConditionType Condition
{
    get
    {
        return this.condition;
    }
    set
    {
        this.condition = value;
        if (condition == ConditionType.Expression)
        {
            var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["ConditionExpressionType"];
            var attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
            FieldInfo isBrow = attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (isBrow != null) isBrow.SetValue(attrib, true);
            descriptor.SetValue(this, attrib);
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Condition");
        this.objExpressionBuilder.NotifyPropertyCheckSelected(this);
    }
}
```

I want to show below Textbox when i select Expression from the dropdown list of property grid.

```
[Category(Constants.ColumnScrambler)]
[DisplayName("Expression")]
[Description("Expression")]
[Browsable(false)]
public string ConditionExpressionType
{
    get { return "TestData"; }
}
```

But the problem is that to do so ,i have to rebind the property grid again and all the values vanished. can anyone please suggest a way without rebind on selection of dropdown list in property grid i can show the text box.